# SQL statement with OLEDB Destination

Tags: t-sql, ssis, oledb

Hi I have OLDDB source and OLEDB destination objects in my Data flow task in SSIS package. I want to join the input from OLEDB source with some other tables in my database to get some IDs and insert in a table. How this can be done either using OLEDB destination or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options but this is by far my preference

### Write SQL!

If you write the SQL statements, including joins and what-not you can use a single OLEDB Source and simply change the **Data access mode** to **SQL command**

[image: OLE DB Source Editor > Data access mode > SQL command]

Comment: I want to execute a insert statement. Not sure how to form the statement like Select coli1,colo2 into temp from <where to select from as the source is oldedb source

Comment: What's the reason of inserting records in a temp?